# How to publish an optimized binary using cargo publish?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am trying to publish my first crate to crates.io.

When I build my project locally, I can pass the `--release` flag to get an optimized binary but when I do `cargo publish --dry-run` it seems to be building an unoptimized binary as this was the second-to-last line of the output:

```
Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 24.79s
```

If possible, I would like to build and publish an optimized binary to crates.io.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You publish source code to crates.io. When a user runs `cargo install <my-crate>`, it downloads the source and compiles it with `--release`. You don't have to do anything.